# How to make a constraint that forces a generic class instance to fit inside a given interface?

Tags: typescript

Having this code:

```js
interface Class {
    new(...args: any[]): any;
}

class Wrapper<C extends Class> {
    asInterface<InstanceType<C> extends I>(): I { // this is where the constraint should go
        return undefined as any as I; // this is not important
    }
}

interface Plane {
    takeoff(): void;
}

interface Car {
    drive(): void;
}

class F35B {
    takeoff() {
        console.log('doing vertical takeoff');
    }
    shoot() {
        console.log('bang bang');
    }
}

const w = new Wrapper<typeof F35B>();
const plane = w.asInterface<Plane>(); // this should pass
const car = w.asInterface<Car>(); // this should not
```

How can I set a constraint on asInterface method such that I is an extension of the instance of constructor C?

Of course the expression, `InstanceType<C> extends I` is not typescript compliant, but that's the key idea of the question.

Comment: Quoting _How can I set a constraint on `asInterface` method such that `I` is an extension of the instance of constructor `C`?_ - The constructor of a class sits in the static side of the class. There methods like `takeoff` sits in instance side of the interface or a class (interaces does not have static side either, actually no side at all). Thus there will be no overlap in the interfaces `Plane` and the constructor of class `F35B`. Though constraint of interface with the class may work(not the constructor). [ref](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#advanced-techniques)

Comment: Finally the expressioin ```InstanceType<C> extends I``` was typescript compliant. It only needs to be part of a ternary expression on the return type as stated in my answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that with a ternary type expression this can be constrained at the return type like this:

```js
interface Class {
    new(...args: any[]): any;
}

type Subtype<I, C extends Class> = InstanceType<C> extends I ? I : never;


class Wrapper<C extends Class> {
    asInterface<I>(): InstanceType<C> extends I ? I : never { // The constraint is the resulting expression
        // @ts-ignore
        return undefined; // this is not important
    }
}

interface Plane {
    takeoff(): void;
}

interface Car {
    drive(): void;
}

class F35B {
    takeoff() {
        console.log('doing vertical takeoff');
    }
    shoot() {
        console.log('bang bang');
    }
}

const w = new Wrapper<typeof F35B>();
const plane = w.asInterface<Plane>();
plane.takeoff();
const car = w.asInterface<Car>();
car.takeoff();
//  ^^^^^^^ Property 'takeoff' does not exists on type never
```

Answer (score 2):

The Typescript way to do this is not to pass `I` as a generic parameter but instead to annotate the assignment as `const plane: Plane = ...` and then let Typescript error if it is not assignable.

There are two other changes that I've made. The first is that your `Class` interface needs to be generic on the instance type or `new` won't return the correct type. The second is that your `Wrapper` needs to accept the wrapped constructor at runtime, it can't just call `new` on a generic parameter `C` because generics are erased at runtime.

So I think the final result will look something like this:

```
interface Class<I> {
    new(...args: any[]): I;
}

class Wrapper<C extends Class<InstanceType<C>>> {
  constructor (private Wrapped: C) {} // <----  `C` is inferred
  create () { return new this.Wrapped() }
}

interface Plane {
    takeoff(): void;
}

interface Car {
    drive(): void;
}

class F35B {
    takeoff() {
        console.log('doing vertical takeoff');
    }
    shoot() {
        console.log('bang bang');
    }
}

const w = new Wrapper(F35B); // <---- Pass constructor at runtime

const plane: Plane = w.create();  // OK

const car: Car = w.create(); // Error
//    ~~~
// Property 'drive' is missing in type 'F35B' but required in type 'Car'
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBs4GcsB4CSAfMgN4BQylyIEA7gBQB0zcUA5lgFzJwgCeAbQC6ASm74A3GQC%20ZMgkw5kAdShwADuui5UyCAA9IIACZY0ivPhBYwvJABU%20WnYVekKyBAHtrYKAFcEMC8oZHp1KGAANzhIFTVNCGNuVBFSaWQAekzkAANUXORgM1AYaCgkjwQK2JR6NJJkCrB-KBBqOmQwAAtixlUNLWN65FlZMlBIWEQUAAVMGncqLrgAawgvGBh67iivYGMpccnoeCQ0ViWqY0ioiB3kPYOjuQVsMwAxAGYAVgAhK6UWzrTbbBoeZaUbzWLzoCCMdBeNj0ADkxn2IDYj2gYGACDg6BWIK2KJEUmWsmWWG6Xi8YBG5EhVGhWFh8MRyJRACNeFieZjSeSqGNXj4bMhaMgALwdSUDRJQejff5krI5XAAWi1GuQs3enjFfkCwVCsSa-nAwAAthBRb5kOoFhBuPNeCgZbRGNUILV6hJKNlkAB5ADSdvF%20KgKUuHq9NUgfrVyAAolAoCEyIGqAA-XOZnKzdNaKBgPjING3CAoopmK3FLCgLGgLpOFAo5V-atc-xgJoQACO-mAFWMRXapa05dQrBRciAA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. Sadly the key thing of my question was to parametrize at method level the interface type. So your answer is not valid for my use case